# How can I make a POST over HTTPS with the requests module in a Sublime Text plugin?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, python-requests, sublimetext3

In a Sublime Text (2 and 3) plugin, I'm using the requests module to make a POST over HTTPS.

```
results = requests.post(secure_url, data=params)
```

This error is created:

```
Sublime Text 2/Packages/requests/all/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

How can I secure this communication in a way that is acceptable to all Sublime instances? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What platform are you on? Do you get the same error with ST3?

Comment: It isn't exception. It's warning. You can ignore it.

Comment: The warning also contains a link to the documentation where it is explained. The documentation also has information on how to suppress this warning (if you know what you are doing by ignoring a security warning).

Comment: @SpeakingCode OP doesn't want to ignore it - he wants a secure connection.

Comment: Try installing `requests` with the `[security]` extra. E.g. `pip install requests[security]`. This will pull in additional dependencies, amongst them `pyOpenSSL`, which should fix this issue.